# Keras.max() - Not behaving as expected with tensor.eval()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, max

My code:

```python
import numpy
numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=numpy.nan)
with tf.Session() as test_a:
    box_confidence = tf.random_normal([3, 4, 5, 1], mean=1, stddev=4, seed = 1)
    boxes = tf.random_normal([3,4, 5, 4], mean=1, stddev=4, seed = 1)
    box_class_probs = tf.random_normal([3, 4, 5, 3], mean=1, stddev=4, seed = 1)
    xxx = box_confidence * box_class_probs
    aaa = K.argmax(xxx, axis=-1)
    bbb = K.max(xxx, axis=-1, keepdims=False)
    print(xxx.eval())
    print(xxx.get_shape())
    print(aaa.eval())
    print(aaa.get_shape())
```

From my understanding, `aaa` takes the index of the maximum of `xxx` in the last dimension (the biggest number of the three numbers in the fourth dimension).

So... Given the tensors values (initialized with fixed seeds), the first row of `aaa` should be `0 2 0 2 0`, right? What I got from the output is `1 1 1 2 1`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The misunderstanding doesn't come from `K.max()` or `K.argmax()`, but from `tensor.eval()`.

Everytime you call `tensor.eval()`, you launch a new run through the graph, so everytime your pseudo-randomly defined tensors get populated with new values as their random seeds are also incremented (using `seed=1` for `tf.random_normal()` doesn't fix the values, it fixes the sequence of pseudo-random values to be generated each run, see [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/set_random_seed) for details).

In other words, `xxx.eval()`, `aaa.eval()` and `bbb.eval()` give you the results for 3 different runs with 3 different random values below.

If you evaluate `xxx`, `aaa` and `bbb` all at once in a single run (`test_a.run([xxx, aaa, bbb])`), you will get the results you were expecting.

---

```python
with tf.Session() as test_a:
    box_confidence = tf.random_normal([3, 4, 5, 1], mean=1, stddev=4, seed=1)
    boxes = tf.random_normal([3,4, 5, 4], mean=1, stddev=4, seed=1)
    box_class_probs = tf.random_normal([3, 4, 5, 3], mean=1, stddev=4, seed=1)
    # note: `seed=1` fixes the seed value and thus the sequence of pseudo-random values.
    #        the PSNR will still yield new values each run, only in a predefined manner.
    xxx = box_confidence * box_class_probs
    aaa = K.argmax(xxx, axis=-1)
    bbb = K.max(xxx, axis=-1, keepdims=False)

    # First run:
    res_xxx, res_aaa, res_bbb = test_a.run([xxx, aaa, bbb])
    print(res_aaa[0, 0])
    # > [0 2 0 2 0]
    # ^ the result you were expecting

    # Second run:
    res_xxx, res_aaa, res_bbb = test_a.run([xxx, aaa, bbb])
    print(res_aaa[0, 0])
    # > [1 1 1 2 1]
    # ^ new result, as new pseudo-random values have been picked inside,
    #   from the sequence predefined by the seeds.
```

Comment: But the random seed is fixed so it would produce same values (?)

Comment: Hi, @Aldream, I tried print(test_a.run([xxx, aaa, bbb])), no, still not the result I expected...

Comment: To be more precise, bbb is right using test_a.run([xxx, aaa, bbb])) for the cases I spot-checked, but aaa is still not right...

Comment: @nuric: Fixing `seed` basically fixes the behavior of the pseudo-random number generator used. New pseudo-random numbers will be generated each run, but in a predefined sequence fixed by the chosen `seed`.

Comment: @TingTing: I'm not sure what you mean. I've edited my answer with a demonstration, with the results you were expecting I believe...?

Comment: @Aldream I don't think that is correct, fixing a seed means you have reproducible random numbers every time, [reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/set_random_seed).

Comment: @nuric: This link to the doc was added to my answer... Fixing the seed, you get a reproducible *sequence* of random numbers generated by your PSNR. Different numbers will be generated each *graph-run* (as you can see from the example added to my answer), but the sequence will be the same each *program-run* (I did mean "*graph-run*" in my previous comment to you, to be clear).

Comment: Hi, yes, when you save the results from test_a.run([xxx, aaa, bbb]) to three numpy arrays, the results are what I expected! but when I just used print (test_a.run([xxx, aaa, bbb])) trying to print out the results, they were still not what I expected...

Comment: does this mean whenever I just want to see the values of a tensor, I have to save it to a numpy array? so troublesome... is there a quicker way just to check the values of tensors? thanks in advance.

Comment: @TingTing: if you want e.g. to print only the 1st inner row of `aaa`, you could directly do `print(test_a.run(aaa)[0, 0])`. Results will be the same if you store them in variables or display them directly. Results will only change each time you call `session.run()` or `tensor.eval()`, as the random tensors you are using will receive new values.

Comment: @Aldream Thank you! ... but print (test_a.run([xxx, aaa, bbb]))  does not work as expected and this upsets me since I consider that within one call...

Comment: @TingTing I am confused, what are you expecting? If you just want to print `xxx` and `aaa`, call `print(test_a.run([xxx, aaa]))`. If it is something else you want, please clarify your question or open a new one.

Comment: When I used print (test_a.run([xxx, aaa, bbb])), I expected aaa to indicate the locations of largest values of xxx in the 4th dimension and bbb to be those maximums... but it is not so. bbb is the maximum of xxx in the 4th dimension but aaa does not indicate those locations correctly...

Comment: `print(test_a.run([xxx, aaa, bbb]))` looks as it should be to me. `aaa[0,0,0]` shows `5.04125023`, which is the value of `xxx[0,0,0,0]` and `bbb[0,0,0]` shows correctly `0` ; `aaa[0,0,1]` shows `23.3469868`, which is the value of `xxx[0,0,1,2]` and `bbb[0,0,1]` shows correctly `2` ; etc.

Comment: (my bad, I mistook `aaa` and `bbb` in my previous comment, e.g. "`bbb[0,0,0]` shows `5.04125023`, which is the value of `xxx[0,0,0,0]` and `aaa[0,0,0]` shows correctly `0`")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172249/discussion-between-tingting-and-aldream).